# Replace elements in list based on a dictionary mapping table

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, mapping

I want to replace the elements in a list of lists based on a dictionary mapping table, and tried below:

```
lists_before = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['D', 'E']]

mapped_dictionary = {'A': 'G',  'B': 'G', 'C':'F'}
```

Below is the code I use:

```
lists_after = []
for element in lists_before:
    new_element  = [] 
    for letter in element :
        if letter in list(mapped_dictionary.values()):
            letter = repl_dic.get(letter)
        new_element.append(letter)
    lists_after.append(new_element)
```

The output expected for lists_after is:

```
[['G', 'G', 'F'],['G','D'],['D','E']]
```

However, the output I got is still the same as lists_before.

I cannot figure out what went wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: `[[mapped_dictionary.get(char, char) for char in sl] for sl in lists_before]`

Comment: Just scratch `.values()`. You need them to be in the `dict` (as in its keys).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

**Input:**

```
l = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['D', 'E']]
m = {'A': 'G',  'B': 'G', 'C': 'F'}
```

**Code:**

```
l_new = list()
for lst in l:
    lst_new = list()
    for ele in lst:
        lst_new.append(m.get(ele, ele))
    l_new.append(lst_new)
```

**Output:**

```
[['G', 'G', 'F'], ['G', 'D'], ['D', 'E']]
```

---

**Or use a 1-liner:**

```
[[m.get(ele, ele) for ele in lst] for lst in l]

[['G', 'G', 'F'], ['G', 'D'], ['D', 'E']]
```